# Scroll графика в c#

Tags: c#, прокрутка, диаграммы

Делаю программу, которая должна довольно длительное время добавлять точки в line chart. Проблем никаких нет, есть только вопрос. Какая настройка отвечает за то, чтобы график не сжимал интервал по оси x, а имел scroll по x и не изменял заданный интервал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить полосу прокрутки:

```
        chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
```

Для изменения масштаба:

```
        chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
        chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Axis.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
```

и в цикле добавления точек указываем позицию точки на графике:

```
       chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Axis.ScaleView.Position = incc;
```